# Downloading and uploading docker images to a different repo in concourse build

Tags: docker, concourse

I want to make certain docker images public (currently private).
So, basically I want the concourse build to download from GCR (private repo and then upload to dockerhub (public repo)

The way I am current doing is using a `docker in docker container` and then runnning the docker commands explicit to first tag and then push to dockerhub.

Can any of the exisiting concourse resources for docker do that automatically?

## EDIT

Turns out, you can do that. In both `docker-image-resource` and `registry-image-resource`, you need to set the tag at the beginning when configuring the resource. However, I want to run a task from which I get the tags and then download the docker image with tag that from a private repo and then upload it to the public repo.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the docker-image-resource can do that. You can find alot mor docs/examples on github: https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource

Here is what i did to build and push images to aws ecr.

First define it as a resource in your pipeline and configure it.

```
resources:
  - name: ecr-repository
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/some/ecr/path
```

Since i was pushing from an ec2 instance i did not need to setup any credentials. When you want to push to docker hub you need to configure the resource with your credentials.

So now concourse knows that resource and it can be used in the jobs steps. In the case of a build/push you would use the put step like so:

```
- put: ecr-repository
  params:
    build: .
```

If your Dockerfile is not in the root of your resource, you can either set build to point to that path, or make use of the dockerfile option. See docsfor more.

Alternativly, There is the registry-image-resource. I have not used that myself yet, but if you already have a working build, you maybe can just give that the artefact you have and push it to where you want. Configuration is propably the same (Give it the url, credentials) and use it in a put step.

https://github.com/concourse/registry-image-resource

**EDIT:**

Both resources have a parameter 'additional_flags'.
To not change your build task, you could output the image as archive along with a file that specifies the tags you want to push.

```
docker save image:latest | gzip > ./outdir/image.tar.gz
echo "some foo tags" > ./outdir/tags_file
```

You can then upload that image with additional tags like this

```
put: registry-resource
    params:
      image: ./outdir/image.tar.gz
      additional_tags: ./outdir/tags_file
```

Of course you must specify 'outdir' as output in the first task and as input in the second task to have concourse transfer the files.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question. Can you check that?

Comment: But, while thinking about it again .... not sure if this is any better then just doing a docker push from where you run the rest of docker anyhow ... :p